# I have a string which contains delimeter as ^ and string as my^name^he^llo^qwerty, I want to split the string and avoid delimeters in some cases

Tags: string, split, escaping, delimiter

I have a string which contains delimeter as ^ and string as my^name^he^llo^qwerty, i want to split the string but using delimeter as ^ giving me output as,

my 
name 
he 
llo 
qwerty

But i need my return strings as 
my 
name
he^llo
qwerty

Please suggest if we can split the string in this fashion avoiding that delimeter in some cases.

Comment: Without using a dictionary to compare possible words or some additional business logic information, I don't see how this is possible. It's like an improper CSV format, where you don't have quotes surrounding words.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have a simple clean way. If you know where you want to keep ^ you can use some other identifier there and replace them after the split. Something like my^name^he@#@llo^qwerty => split with ^ then replace @#@ with ^. Or do as @Eric has said above.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I have added as per your suggestions got the output as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the `delimiter` specifically different which will not be used in `Strings`, As there is no simple way to achieve the `splitting of string` in some cases and avoid it in some cases.